# Backtesting in R for time series

Tags: r, for-loop, back-testing

I am new to the backtesting methodology - algorithm in order to assess if something works based on the historical data.Since I am new to that I am trying to keep things simple in order to understand it.So far I have understood that if let's say I have a data set of time series : [image]

```
date = seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"),as.Date("2001/1/31"), by = "day")
n = length(date);n
class(date)
y = rnorm(n)
data = data.frame(date,y)
```

I will keep the first 365 days that will be the in sample period in order to do something with them and then I will update them with one observation at the time for the next month.Am I correct here ?

So if I am correct, I define the in sample and out of sample periods.

```
T = dim(data)[1];T
outofsampleperiod = 31
initialsample = T-outofsampleperiod
```

I want for example to find the quantile of alpha =0.01 of the empirical data.

```
pre = data[1:initialsample,]
ypre = pre$y
quantile(ypre,0.01)
      1% 
-2.50478
```

Now the difficult part for me is to update them in a for loop in R.

I want to add each time one observation and find again the empirical quantile of alpha = 0.01.To print them all and check the condition if is greater than the in sample quantile as resulted previously.

```
for (i in 1:outofsampleperiod){

 qnew = quantile(1:(initialsample+i-1),0.01)
 print(qnew)
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a little function that gets the quantile of column `y`, over rows 1 to `i` of a frame `df` like this:

```
func <- function(i,df) quantile(df[1:i,"y"],.01)
```

Then apply this function to each row of `data`

```
data$qnew = lapply(1:nrow(data),func,df=data)
```

Output (last six rows)

```
> tail(data)
          date          y      qnew
392 2001-01-26  1.3505147 -2.253655
393 2001-01-27 -0.5096840 -2.253337
394 2001-01-28 -0.6865489 -2.253019
395 2001-01-29  1.0881961 -2.252701
396 2001-01-30  0.1754646 -2.252383
397 2001-01-31  0.5929567 -2.252065
```

Comment: Here what is the qnew?Are you updating the insamle period sample with the new?Can you please edit your answer in order to understand what you are doing?Your answer is very helpful thought.Thank you very much @langtang

Comment: My full apology if I misunderstood your question. I understand that you are trying to estimate the 0.01 quantile of y over the first 365 days, then the first 366 days, then over the first 367 days, etc... The function should allow you do do that.. If you want the 0.01 quantile of `y` over the first 78 days of `data`, for example, you can do `func(78,data)`..  The `lapply` statement applying that function for each of the days from 1 to nrow(data) (i.e over all the rows of the data), and returning the values in a list; I assign that list to a new col called `qnew`

Comment: You understood correct as you explain very clear in the first 4 rows of your comment.

Comment: In my edit I added a picture to understand the full picture of backtesting.